# Android: How do I make a portion of an ImageView transparent?

Tags: java, android

I am wondering how I make a **portion** of an `ImageView` transparent (**not the whole image**). The reason for this is because I want to place an `ImageView` on top of another `ImageView`, but I want the right half of the top `ImageView` transparent so the right half of the bottom `ImageView` is showing, as displayed in the diagram below:

[image]

Below is the code for making an `ImageView` transparent, but I want to make just the right 50% of the `ImageView` transparent:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setAlpha(0);
```

Comment: Adam, is this question still relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine two bitmaps according to ur positions and set it in single imageview.

```
public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap c, Bitmap s) { 
    Bitmap cs = null; 

    int width, height = 0; 

    if(c.getWidth() > s.getWidth()) { 
      width = c.getWidth() + s.getWidth(); 
      height = c.getHeight(); 
    } else { 
      width = s.getWidth() + s.getWidth(); 
      height = c.getHeight(); 
    } 

    cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 

    Canvas finalImage= new Canvas(cs); 

    finalImage.drawBitmap(c, 0f, 0f, null); 
    finalImage.drawBitmap(s, c.getWidth(), 0f, null); 

    return cs; 
}  


ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageBitmap(combineImages(bitmap1,bitmap2);
```